# Symfony Entity Factory with DiscriminatorColumn not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this entity Contact.php

```
#[ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name: 'type', type: 'string')]
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap([
    'person' => ContactType\Person::class,
    'family' => ContactType\Family::class,
    'company' => ContactType\Company::class,
])]
```

and also the Factory like this:

```
protected function getDefaults(): array
    {
        return [
            'createdAt' => self::faker()->dateTime(),
            'isArchived' => 0,
            ...
            'type' => Person::class,
        ];
    }
```

In my AppFixtures file I have something like this:

```
public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $user = UserFactory::createOne();
        $contacts = ContactFactory::createMany(5, [
            'createdBy' => $user
        ]);

        $manager->flush();
    }
```

calling the command `php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load` is ending up in this error:

```
In Instantiator.php line 84:
                                                                                           
  Cannot set attribute "type" for object "App\Entity\Contact" (not public and no setter).  
                                                                                           

In PropertyAccessor.php line 544:
                                                                                      
  Could not determine access type for property "type" in class "App\Entity\Contact".
```

My goal here is to have working Fixtures so I can test the code or just create myself dummy data.
I have no idea what to do in this or even where to look. Any suggestions are more then welcomed.

Comment: Can you post your declaration of the "type" property in your Contact entity?

Comment: To quote the inheritance mapping page: A mapped superclass is an abstract or concrete class that provides persistent entity state and mapping information for its subclasses, but which is not itself an entity. (let that sink in for a moment) I.e. you should not be able to create a Contact object but only instances of its subclasses. The error message you're getting suggests, that you're trying to do exactly that (or whatever framework does this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DiscriminatorColumn` and `DisciminatorMap` is used by Class Table Inheritence (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.17/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance).

You specify 3 mapped types (each one is present in DiscriminatorMap) : `Person`, `Family` and `Company`.

```php
#[ORM\DiscriminatorMap([
    'person' => ContactType\Person::class,
    'family' => ContactType\Family::class,
    'company' => ContactType\Company::class,
])]
```

But the exception say you trying to create a Contact and there is no type on it.

Can you edit your question with ContactFactory ? Did you create a Contact class or a Person class ?

Comment: exactly this was the issue. I tried to create a Contact and of course there is no type there. If I try to create a Person, then all works. Thank you for you answer :)